# New accounts in Debian have no corresponding mail inbox file in /var/mail

Tags: email, debian-etch

I can't for the life of me understand why all of a sudden no mailboxes are being created for new accounts on my Debian server.  The mailbox files are usually located in /var/mail

I create a user by typing in the following command:

## useradd -md /home/fred  fred

As far as I can remember, this was all that was needed.

Is there something right under my nose that I am missing ?

I am using Postfix and Dovecot on this box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the mail spool file will be created when the first email comes in.. useradd will not add the file

Answer (score 1):

You have to add  mailuser from postfixadmin. After that  you cant add  alies  to system users.

Answer (score 1):

In Debian (Lenny), there is a config file named `/etc/default/useradd`. Have a look in there. At the bottom of my local copy, I see this:

```
# Defines whether the mail spool should be created while
# creating the account
# CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes
```

Check whether your copy has that setting commented the same as mine does. If so, uncommenting it should get `useradd` to behave the way you want.

Comment: Thanks all.

this did it:

In Debian (Lenny), there is a config file named /etc/default/useradd. Have a look in there. At the bottom of my local copy, I see this:
Defines whether the mail spool should be created while
creating the account
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes

Check whether your copy has that setting commented the same as mine does. If so, uncommenting it should get useradd to behave the way you want.

I really appreciate all the help. Thanks!!!